# UIimagepickercontroller crash in iPhone 5 ios 6

Tags: ios, crash, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-5

> "Apps that crash will be rejected: We found that your app crashed on iPhone 5 and iPad running iOS 6"

This works on the simulator IOS 6.

```
self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imgPicker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
self.imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
[self.imgPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
```

Iphone 5 is not in sale and I can not test on a real device.
Help me please...

Comment: I don't see anything about checking if the source type is available.

Comment: if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])?